# Merging text from google sheets columns to google drive txt file

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to figure out a function to merge data from multiple columns into one txt file on google drive. For example: Column 1, Column 2 and Column 3 would result in a text file that will have them like this "textrow1 - textrow2 - textrow3" and data from Column 5 would create a separate file with "textrow5".

Using this function to create the separate files for each column but would want it to create only 2 text files with the specified columns only.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 3; // Skip first two rows => start at 3rd
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var columns = rows[0].map((_, colIndex) => rows.map(row => row[colIndex]));
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("bonushunt").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
   var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  columns.forEach(function(column, index) {
    folder.createFile("column" + index + ".txt", column.join("\n")); // New line
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a file for columns A-B-C, where each value in a row will be separated by `" - "`, and each row will be in a new line `"\n"`, as well as another file for column E. If that's the case:

- I don't think it's necessary to transpose the array. I'd suggest you to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to retrieve the data from the desired columns (`A to C` and `E`).
- For files that should have several columns, you can use `map` and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate all values in each row with `" - "` as a separator.
- Since you want to make the same actions several times (but not based on looping through an array), I'd suggest you to create another function to handle the file creation itself.

#### Code sample:

```
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 3;
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var cols_AC = rows.map(row => row.slice(0, 3)); // Get columns A-B-C
  var col_E = rows.map(row => row.slice(4, 5)); // Get column E
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("bonushunt").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  createTxt(folder, "columns_AC", cols_AC);
  createTxt(folder, "column_E", col_E);
}
    
function createTxt(folder, fileName, data) {
  var fileContent = data.map(row => row.join(" - ")).join("\n");
  folder.createFile(fileName + ".txt", fileContent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is exactly what I was looking for. Have a great day and thanks again.